# web2py git integration - localhost & pythonanywhere

Tags: python, git, github, web2py, pythonanywhere

I have absolutely no idea how to integrate Github into web2py.  I have web2py installed on a usb and also on [pythonanywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com).

The web2py overview document chapter3 http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview says :

Git integration

The admin app also includes git integration. Python git libraries are required, e.g.

> `pip install gitpython`

This doesn't mean a thing to me!!?  I am just getting into programming and trying to make sure everything is set up properly!

Any help would be really appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

`pip install gitpython` is a command to type into a command line.  That would be a "Bash console" on PythonAnywhere, a "Terminal" on a Mac or Linux, or a "Command Prompt" on Windows.  It tells the system to install the Python package called "gitpython"

However, in order to make it work, you'll need to install pip (except on PythonAnywhere, where it's already installed).  There are [instructions on how to do that here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html).

Comment: What about after the gitpython module is installed? Where do you configure the git repository it is connected to and where do you enter a username/password for GitHub?