# Integration Github with web2py web application

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, web2py, web2py-modules

How we can integrate GitHub with "web2py" project.I want to connect may application to github.

Comment: You need to be more specific, what kind of integration you need?

Comment: I just want when i "commit" or "push" on github webhook send json regarding commit message etc on given url i.e. http://abc:8000/controller/function. I have successfully hit the controller but  json not recieve

Comment: There are some instructions on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330784/web2py-git-integration-localhost-pythonanywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the json request as a Storage object using:

```
request.post_vars
```